# Java: Generic Type type mismatch syntax error

Tags: java, generics

I have this declaration/initiation written for Java JDK 1.6

```
Map<String, <? extends List<?>>> groupThemTogether = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String[]>>();
```

The error happens at the first comma. The error message is

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashMap<String,ArrayList<String[]>> to Map<String,List>

Why doesn't this compile?

Comment: Oops, this compiled for me (*removed previous post as I copied the wrong code*) `Map<String, ? extends List<?>> groupThemTogether = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String[]>>();`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got too many angle brackets. Try this:

```
Map<String, ? extends List<?>> groupThemTogether = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String[]>>();
```

This compiles for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure of this?

This, similar code, compiles OK for me:

```
Map<String, ? extends List<?>> groupThemTogether = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String[]>>();
```